# Unable to locate package vsftpd Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 17.10, execute-command

I am using below command to install ftp but its showing error message:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

**Error**

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vsftpd
```

Comment: I just looked on my 17.10 box; it's located in 'main' and it was instantly located on my ubuntu mirror. I'd check your sources.list to see where it's pointing; maybe switch-to or add another mirror.

Comment: I am configuring new digitalocean droplet facing this error can you suggest me any thing

Comment: *maybe switch-to or add another mirror* is a suggestion.

Comment: which other mirror is good

Comment: the best mirror for you depends upon your location.  for example I list my isp's mirror; then my countries ubuntu [au.*.ubuntu.com because i'm in au], then  finally *.ubuntu.com or the default ubuntu.com site

Comment: ok, now I try to login with FTP without vsftpd installation and its working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to resynchronize the package index files from their sources before installing the package?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Comment: i tried your command but its showing same error message

Comment: What is the content of your source.list ? are you able to install other packages such as vim or nano? did you try resetting your source.list ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed my Singapore droplet mirror and changed mirror from Singapore to Newyork and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `.deb` archive for [amd64](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/vsftpd_3.0.3-12_amd64.deb.html) and/or [i386](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-i386/vsftpd_3.0.3-12_i386.deb.html) from these links. Go to the directory that you downloaded the `.deb` archive to, and install the package manually by:

```
sudo dpkg -i "packageName.deb" #replace the text in quotes with the name of the package you downloaded
sudo apt-get install -f  # to fix any dependencies that might be broken.
```